# References on the submodules of a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, direct-sum

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of all prime numbers. Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-Module $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{P})}$, that is, the external direct sum of copies of the additive abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ indexed in the set of prime numbers.

Does anybody know any books or articles where I can read about this object? In particular, I'm looking for any characterization of it's submodules.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: It is canonically isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}^{\times}$. Submodules are simply subgroups.

Comment: @Servaes: almost; you need to quotient out by $-1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sharp as always, too late to edit unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in Servaes' comment, presumably this question was inspired by trying to understand the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ of the rationals. Note that abstractly you don't need to know anything about $\mathbb{P}$ other than that it's countably infinite, so it's equivalent to just study the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

This is a free module, and [submodules of free modules over a PID are free](http://people.math.sc.edu/mcnulty/algebra/grad/pidfree.pdf). So every submodule is the span of some linearly independent set of elements. I'm not sure what else there is to say other than this.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. That being said, I would argue that there is something in the nature of this direct sum that makes it different from $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ since in this article (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869316000612) they use it for an example, and the authors specifically use the sum I asked about. Naturally I thoguht about using $\mathbb{N}$ as the indexing set, but unfortunately I was unable to prove that either were an example of the objects that are being treated in the article.

Comment: There is no difference; any bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the prime numbers exhibits an isomorphism between them. Can you quote the relevant section of that article? I don't have access to it.

Comment: They state that $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{P})}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}$ is an example of an isoartinian module. 
We say that an $R$-Module $M$ is isoartinian iff for every nonempty set $\Gamma$ of submodules of $M$, there exists $N\in\Gamma$ such that, for every $N'\leq N$, if $N'\in\Gamma$, then $N'\cong N$.